# Lewis Structure of SO2

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, lewis-structure

What is the structure of SO<sub>2</sub>? I have seen two different ways the Lewis Structure is written:
[image: Single and Double]
[image: Two double bonds]

The formal charges of the SO<sub>2</sub> with the single bond and a double bond is larger than the SO<sub>2</sub> with two double bonds. So I would assume that the one with two double bonds is the correct structure. But chemistry books I have looked at (Zumdahl Edition 5 and 7) says that it is the opposite.

Which is the correct Lewis Structure?

Comment: There is such thing as a "correct Lewis structure."

Comment: [SO2 Lewis Structure - How to Draw the Lewis Structure for SO2 (Sulfur Dioxide)](https://youtu.be/REugD0mJxPk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lewis structure most closely resembling reality consists of two resonance structures: the first one posted in the question and its mirror image. The reason is that the octet rule is observed this way (no hybridization of d-orbitals for main group chemistry necessary or possible) as well as the symmetry of the molecule: the two bonds are identical.

Comment: I had the notion that sulfur had expanded valence electrons. So why wouldn't sulfur be able to use them and make the formal charges get to 0 for all three atoms? Also, how does the molecule have symmetry? The bonds aren't identical, one is a single bond and the other is a double bond.

Comment: The identical bonds are a physically observable reality. Expanded valence electrons are an outdated concept refuted by modern quantum chemistry.

Comment: How does sulfur make a molecule such as Sulfur Hexafluoride in modern quantum chemistry, since expanded valence electrons are outdated?

Comment: @Hawkeye check out molecular orbital theory.  You can easily hold sulfur hexafluoride together without using "outer $d$ orbitals".